# Managing subdomains in the new Google Analytics user interface

Tags: google-analytics, settings, subdomain

I have the following domain structure:

mydomain.com

www.mydomain.com

site1.mydomain.com

site2.mydomain.com

What I need:

- a profile to report all the traffic for all these domains together as one
- a profile to report only the traffic for mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com as one (they actually are the same server alias, just a user preference whether use or not use the www, so I would like to merge both together)
- a profile to report only the traffic for site1.mydomain.com
- a profile to report only the traffic for site2.mydomain.com

Those sites are essentially a part of one web application, so I would like to use only a single tracking code.

I am pretty new to GA, so I have looked some tutorials on the web, but mostly they are outdated and screenshots are from older GA user interface. Even Google Help documentation seems to be a bit outdated, so I am confused about how to set up everything in a clean way.

What I have so far: I created an account for mydomain.com. I selected the radio option that this tracking code is for "One domain with multiple subdomains" and Google gave me the following tracking code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomain.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

NOTICE: there is no dot before mydomain.com. Some web tutorials say, it should be there and some tutorials say that it is ok to leave it without the dot.

Google has created a profile:
mydomain.com [DEFAULT]
for me.

Now I am able to see the traffic separately by Hostname (Technology -> Network, and click Hostname in the table below the chart), but I would like to have a easier access to the Hostname filter, so they are already applied when I click on the profile name.

I tried to create a new profile site1.mydomain.com and added a filter:
Predefined filter
Include only -> traffic from the domains -> that are equal to -> site1.mydomain.com
The filter appeared at the filters list for that profile, but still when I open the report, I see all the traffic together, including mydomain.com and site1.mydomain.com.

What would be the most straight forward way to set up the profiles for my needs using the new Google Analytics User Interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, i'd canonicalize your default website URL (with "www." for **everyone** (or **no one**)) - for SEO reasons (http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/).

Now to the answer:

The reason to place the DOT "." on your **_setDomainName** (like '.mydomain.com') is to leave the cookies available for the visitors across your subdomains.
That means that one visiting "site1.mydomain.com" and then going to "www.mydomain.com" would be treated as the **same visit**.

Hence, without the dot, you would get duplicate visits on your "get all" profile, once a visitor changes subdomains.
(more on that here: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setDomainName)

About the filter, instead of a Predefined Filter, try creating a **Custom Filter** of **Include** for the **Hostname**. Then for the **pattern** you'd create a Regex looking something like **^site1\.mydomain\.com$**

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

you should setup a filter to add hostname in your main profile, that compares subdomains

then setup a profile for each site, filter only traffic on that subdomain

just prey you dont have a 2-letter domain xx.com, then you wont have IE traffic, only the other browsers. I have that issue, and cant solve without messing up my 150-190 subdomains on the site :)

rgds